# Xlib. Check if window is overlapped

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I need to check (in my C++ application) if application's window is overlapped (partially or completely) by another window. How can I get this info using xlib?

I tried get `WM_STATE` property of the window and compare it with NormalState. However, when I overlap target window my condition (`state != NormalState`) wasn't executed. I also tried to compare `_NET_WM_STATE` property with `_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN` and this method didn't give needed result.

I tried to implement suggested by `spectras` solution, and now it looks like working variant(Note: `GetWindowProperty` is my wrapper around corresponding Xlib function):

```
bool ApplicationHelper::IsWindowOverlapped(const void* hWnd, _XDisplay* pd)
{
    Display* pDisplay = pd == nullptr ? XOpenDisplay(nullptr) : pd;
    if(pDisplay == nullptr)
    {
        return true;
    }
    auto root = XDefaultRootWindow(pDisplay);
    Window parent;
    /*Window* windowList;
    unsigned nchildren;
    if (!XQueryTree(pDisplay, root, &root, &parent, &windowList, &nchildren))
    {
        if(pd == nullptr)
        {
            XCloseDisplay(pDisplay);
        }
        return true;
    }*/

    Atom propCleints = XInternAtom(pDisplay, "_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING", True);
    unsigned long ulBytesReturned = 0;
    Window *windowList = (Window *)GetWindowProperty(pDisplay, root, propCleints, &ulBytesReturned);
    unsigned long nchildren = ulBytesReturned / sizeof(Window);
    int32_t actualDesktop = GetWindowDesktop(pDisplay, (TWindow) hWnd);

    WindowRect targetWindowRect;
    GetWindowRect(hWnd, targetWindowRect, pDisplay);
    GdkRectangle targetGdkRect;
    targetGdkRect.x = targetWindowRect.x;
    targetGdkRect.y = targetWindowRect.y;
    targetGdkRect.width = targetWindowRect.width;
    targetGdkRect.height = targetWindowRect.height;
    bool handleWindow = false;
    bool res = false;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < nchildren; ++i)
    {
        auto window = windowList[i];
        if((Window)hWnd == window)
        {
            handleWindow = true;
            continue;
        }
        if(handleWindow)
        {
            if((GetWindowDesktop(pDisplay, window) != actualDesktop) || IsWindowHidden((void*)window, pDisplay))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                WindowRect rc;
                GetWindowRect((void*)window, rc, pDisplay);
                GdkRectangle gdkRect;
                gdkRect.x = rc.x;
                gdkRect.y = rc.y;
                gdkRect.width = rc.width;
                gdkRect.height = rc.height;
                if(gdk_rectangle_intersect(&targetGdkRect, &gdkRect, nullptr))
                {
                    res = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    XFree(windowList);
    if(pd == nullptr)
    {
        XCloseDisplay(pDisplay);
    }

    return res;
}
```

This code always returns true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, as its name says, that property only signals whether the window is being hidden (for instance because it is minimized).

If you want to check for other windows above yours and hiding part of it, you'll have to do it manually.

For instance, this gets a list of all top-level windows:

```
auto root = XDefaultRootWindow(display);
Window parent;
Window * children;
unsigned nchildren;
if (!XQueryTree(display, root, &root, &parent, &children, &nchildren)) {
    std::cout <<"Failed to query top level windows list\n";
    return 1;
}

for (unsigned idx = 0; idx < nchildren; ++idx) {
    auto window = children[idx];
    // do something with window
}

XFree(children);
```

You will need to:

- Find out where your own window is in the list. Any window that comes **after** it is above in the stacking order.
- Query the desktop of each window above yours (`_NET_WM_DESKTOP` atom), eliminate any window not show on current desktop.
- Query the display state of each window above yours (`_NET_WM_STATE` atom, looking for `_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN` atom in the list).
- Query the size of each shown window above yours. Possibly using the [Shape extension](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XShape.3.html) if you want to account for non-rectangular windows
- Check whether any of those intersect with your own display area.

Comment: Thanks. Will try and update you with results. For now it looks clear and workable.

Comment: I implemented suggested solution and updated my initial post. However my code always returns true.

Comment: Then it's wrong. You didn't post your whole code so it's hard to say. I know for sure this approach works. Dealing with xlib is tricky though, there are many mistakes that can trap the unwary implementer.

Comment: actually it is whole function. In the function I tried to implement all the steps you described above. To check the intersection area I use `gdk_rectangle_intersect` function, because I didn't find Xlib corresponding function. What parts of code I need to show to make it more clear for you to understand?

Comment: did you debug and check whether your IsWindowHidden or GetWindowProperty functions return the appropriate values? Also, you might want to check out [minimal complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I updated my post with working code. However it works only with `_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING`-way of getting top level windows. When I use `XQueryTree` for getting windows, it doesn't work. What the difference between these approaches?

Comment: XQueryTree will have all windows, while `_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING` only has the windows under window manager's control. So the difference could come either from the filtering function failing to eliminate some invisible windows present in XQueryTree but not managed by window manager, or from actually having windows covering yours (watch for 1x1 windows in the top-left corner notably).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to combine both of these variants. Mark the question as solved. Thank you for you help